# access resources from html file

Tags: c#, html, resources

Okay, so I have a resource file (.resx) in my c# project. Inside it, I have a html layout and a small image. How would I fetch the image from the resx file from inside the html file?

Can it be done without code?

/Dynde

Answer (score 0):

link help you.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982.aspx

Comment: Okay, I might have been a little quick in my description, but I can't use c# at all - embedded or otherwise, as the html file is being sent as an email. But I'm guessing the only way to achieve what I need is to embed the image programmatically before sending the email.

Comment: Since it is email, you'll definitely need to do it prior to sending.  You're not going to be able to execute any code in the email client, web, or desktop.

Comment: @Dynde the answer to your initial question should be: `<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%$ Resources:WebResourcesGlobal, ImageUrl %>"/>`, but since you send it via email, it's better to embed it before you send it (as Matthew said). But you still could store it in the .resx file and access it in the code behind.

Comment: Exactly - I knew I couldn't execute any code, that's why I wondered if there was any strictly markup way of fetching recourse files, but as have been confirmed, this isn't the case :/ thanks anyway